# Python How to top list of dicts up

Tags: python

```
[{'month': 7.0, 'sumd': 11}, {'month': 8.0, 'sumd': 20}]
```

I have this list. This is aggregation of months and some values. How to top it up by 0 to get something like this?

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

EDIT
This first list has dicts with only this months which has something in sumd. If month does't have any information in sumd it will not be in list.

But in second list I need only value from sumd order by months number(but with all months - if any months was not in first list, set 0.)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'top it up', what the relation between your dictionary and array is and what you want to change.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to provide any sort of information?

Comment: Step 1: Create a list of zeroes. Step 2: Loop through your list of dictionaries, updating the appropriate indices in your array. We're not going to write code for you, especially if you don't give any information about what you've tried already.

Comment: FWIW, I'm guessing that what he wants to do is to take the 'sumd' value in each dict and put it at the position, represented by 'month', in a new list (i.e. item 7 in the list should be 11, item 8 should be 20 ...). It looks to me like he accidentally added an extra zero at the beginning of his sample list (i.e. 11 s/b the 7th value, not the 8th).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood what you want to do, the result would be a list of 12 elements not 13.

So if you cant to put the value of the month number (value of the month key) in the array representing a year (12 elements) you can do this :

```
month_dictionaries = [{'month': 7.0, 'sumd': 11}, {'month': 8.0, 'sumd': 20}]

result = [0] * 12

for d in month_dictionnaries:
    if 'sumd' in d.keys():
        result[int(d['month']) - 1] = d['sumd']
```

Comment: Don't call .keys, you are doing at best an unnecessary function call or at worst changing an `O(1)` lookup to `O(n)`

Comment: He have to test if there is a `'sumd'` key in the dictionary.
What do you suggest ? a `try: d['sumd'] except keyError: continue` ?

Answer (score 0):

For the sample you have provided this should work:

```
values = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
month_values = [{'month': 7.0, 'sumd': 11}, {'month': 8.0, 'sumd': 20}]

for m in  month_values:
    values[(int(m['month'])-1)]=m['sumd']
```

Comment: @depperm because it starts indexing in python from 0 not 1.

Comment: I realize that but look at his example his month may be counting from 0 already

Comment: @depperm , accepted answer has also -1 so I guess it's ok

Answer (score 0):

I'll take `sumd` to imply that you want to add up overlapping months. And you can fix the indexing to get 12 months, not 13

```
data = [{'month': 7.0, 'sumd': 11}, {'month': 8.0, 'sumd': 20}]

months = [0]*12

for d in data:
    idx = int(d['month']) - 1
    v = d['sumd']
    months[idx] += v
```